# Organizing TreeView nodes in a table

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, treeview

I am currently searching for a way to present data in a TreeView in a more organized way. I was looking for combining TreeView with grid view and I know several people have tried this before but I was not able to adapt these information on my problem as I have no idea about XAML up to know and barely time to learn it.
Thats the way it currently looks like:

[image: old TreeView]

I would like to have the details directly below the headings but I have no idea how to do this.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Kind regards

Larimow

Comment: Search for WPF `TreeListView` on the internet.

Comment: I found one good page on code project but the demo source code does not work on my system for an unknown reason.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ObjectListView - I think this is the easiest way!

Comment: I had a look at ObjectListView but it's not combine able with WPF as far as I know.